# Removing li from ul

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Requirement Background:**
I am building an appointment booking page.
I have a function that generates dates and creates a custom calendar using UL LI. These dates have appointment availability respectively.
The requirement is to show a loader when we click on next or previous month buttons, if we are on slow network or delay in the ajax to load new dates. For this the idea is to remove all the LI from UL as soon as that function gets called and once ajax is complete then add the newly loaded LIs in UL.

**Problem:**
The function works perfectly, however in chrome after the existing LIs are removed from UL, it still shows the dates for sometime. This is driving me crazy, but I checked in inspect mode and the UL is empty ([please check the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmHfY.jpg)), but the dates are still visible.

In order to test this, I set the network speed to Slow 3G. I have tried,

```
$("ul").html("")

$("ul").empty()
```

I also tried adding `display: none` `visibility: hidden` etc. to the LIs and UL everything works but chrome still shows the dates instead of hiding or removing them.

Please help.

Comment: `in chrome after the existing LIs are removed from UL, it still shows the dates for sometime` the only way I could see this happening is if you're using a synchronous AJAX request and the UI is not updated before the thread is blocked. Please add a more complete example of your HTML and JS to the question as what you have shown is not enough to help you effectively

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can properly understand the issue and be able to help you. There's not enough code or contextual information in your question for us to work out what's actually happening

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan for your comment. Actually I can't post the exact code but I'll try to see if I can create a fiddle or something. Also, I'm new to jquery so I'll have to look into this synchronous AJAX request if that is what is happening :)